# JPA OneToOne and OneToMany : updates and deletions

Tags: jpa

I want a model object to contain another with a relation OneToOne, but I want the second object automatically updated when the first is saved (object.save()), and automatically deleted when the first is deleted.

I have the same need with an object containing a list of other object, with the same requirements for save/update and delete. With the particular case : when the first object is saved, I want the second object to be updated, created or deleted according the new list in first object.

A similar example is a blog post with comments that can be added, edited or deleted.

I have done many tries, using "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" and other "mappedBy", the tries are done in unit test with HSQLDB, with I cannot avec any sucess ... :-(

Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Xavier

Comment: using cascades is usually the way to go. Do you get any errors? How do you check for success? Can you post the code?

Comment: The cascade is working when I save the first object, but for each saving, a new second object is created in the DB and the previous line is not removed from table ... I expected that the DB was correctly updated : updating the second object or removing the previous data to create a new one

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue could be without seeing the code. Please post the entities with their mappings, equals and hashCode (no setters getters) and at least one of the failing tests

Comment: https://github.com/xnopre/test-play-jpa/. It's not my product code but a sample code. In this code, it seems to be OK for OneToMany, but tests failed at JpaTests:83 : there are 2 PostDetails in DB instead of 1, the previous and unused PostDetails is not deleted

Comment: For future readers : link to the original code : https://github.com/xnopre/test-play-jpa/tree/9b16869daa093243ea4a8b0857e9337a667967f1

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue - the declared `orphanRemoval=true` is not working properly - the `PostDetails` entity should be deleted after it is no longer referenced by a `Post`.

This seems to be an issue with Hibernate - the orphan removal does not work as one would expect. Please see [**this post**](http://mcls.github.com/blog/2012/08/07/pojo-binding-and-jpas-orphanremoval-in-play/) explaining how to work around it in Play.

And [**this**](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6484) and [**this**](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5559) seem to be the relevant bug tickets for Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the same problem, my problem is with OneToOne. I have found a solution, seen on the web, replacing the OneToOne by a OneToMany on a List, ensuring that there always is only one instance. It works. It seems that "orphanRemoval=true" is not well managed on OneToOne. The new code : https://github.com/xnopre/test-play-jpa/tree/67aea06219c8b1026b65c29189e05009d52f2bc0

Comment: @xnopre - cool, glad you got it figured out. You could post your solution as an answer and accept it - for future readers. And I will leave my wrong answer here for reference.